# Google maps with destination textboxes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wanting to imbed google maps into a website with two textboxes. I am wanting to place a destination in each textbox and then press a 'Go' button which traces the route from the two destinations that are entered in the two textboxes.

If google maps is not the easiest way to do this, is there another provider that I can use this idea with.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {

    var rendererOptions = {
            draggable: true
        };

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);

    var my_place = new google.maps.LatLng(17.435979,78.448196);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: my_place
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById("Start").value;
  var end = document.getElementById("Destination").value;
  var request = {
     origin:start, 
     destination:end,
     travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
 });
}
$(function(){
    initialize();
});
</script>

<div id='map_canvas' style='width: 500px; height: 400px'></div>
<form name="GoogleMapForm" method="post" action="">
Start: <input type="text" name="Start" id="Start" /><br />
Destination: <input type="text" name="Destination" id="Destination" /><br />
<input type="button" name="Go" value="Go" onclick="javascript: calcRoute()" />
</form>
```

Above code help to get what you required. Form has Start & Destination Textboxes where you have to enter address manually. If you want a autocomplete for these textboxes(i.e., guide you when you type the address follow this link "https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete").

Comment: Thanks heaps munna. Sorry, I don't know much Javascript, can you please modify this so that I can paste is straight into the HTML source code of an editor (or explain to me how to implement the above code). Currently I am using FrontPage.

Comment: Not much to do Garry.... Place <script> tag set of code in head section... and after <div> tag code in body section... it starts working...all the best

Comment: OK munna, I have got it displayed the two and from destination textboxes. However, no imbedded map is showing up. Also, as a side note, do you recommend I play around with a widget/gadget that works? If so, what one do you recommend? I have tried a few, yet none work as I am expecting it to.

Comment: Hey! Garry! sorry there was a mistake in a code. Replace src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" to src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" for demo please check the link "http://sailesh.in/gcode.html"